# How to use localstorage with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

When I add new task to my task manager it saves it in localStorage but cannot show it on the page without updating.  Do I need to use $watch or maybe something else?

Code is here:

```js
$scope.retrievedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
$scope.addTask = function() {
  console.log($scope.retrievedTasks)
  console.log($scope.tasks)
  if ($scope.newTaskName) {
    $scope.tasks.push({
      taskName: $scope.newTaskName,
      status: false
    });
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify($scope.tasks));
    $scope.newTaskName = "";
  }
};
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="task in retrievedTasks">
  <td>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteTask(task)">Delete</button>
    <!--  $index-->
  </td>
  <td>{{task.taskName}}</td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="statusCheck"> </td>
  <td style="{{setStyleToTd(statusCheck)}}">{{statusChecker(statusCheck)}}</td>
  <td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editTask(task)">Edit</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: also I tried to use $window.localstorage but it didnt work:(

Comment: Do you actually need two scope variables -$scope.retrievedTasks and $scope.tasks? If no, just replace $scope.retrievedTasks  with  $scope.tasks in both html and js.

Answer (score 0):

your view is using `retrievedTasks` while your controller updates `$scope.tasks` so if you want to keep using `retrievedTasks` you should make sure to push it onto that list

```
$scope.addTask = function () {
    if ($scope.newTaskName) {
        $scope.retrievedTasks.push({
            taskName: $scope.newTaskName
            , status: false
        });
        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify($scope.retrievedTasks));
        $scope.newTaskName = "";
    }
};
```

Comment: some angular error in console, maybe it because i use localstorage instead of angular alternative? Ive seen some $localStorage stuff

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you.

```
 $scope.retrievedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
 $scope.addTask = function() 
 {
  console.log($scope.retrievedTasks)
  console.log($scope.tasks)
  if ($scope.newTaskName) {
    $scope.tasks = {
        taskName: $scope.newTaskName,
        status: false
    };
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify($scope.tasks));
    $scope.newTaskName = "";
  }
 };`enter code here`
```